# Error in db_query statement - d7

Tags: 7, database

The below query is giving error:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in webform_options_submit()

What am I missing? Any suggestions/ideas will be helpful.

And, How should I use the LIKE command in this query?

```
  $args = array(':entities' => $_REQUEST['entities'], ':countries'=>$_REQUEST['countries']);
  $query = db_query("SELECT field_entity_value,field_country_value, filename
                   FROM field_data_field_entity,field_data_field_country , field_revision_field_file_upload, file_managed
                   WHERE ( field_data_field_entity.field_entity_value LIKE :entities
                   AND field_data_field_country.field_country_value= :countries )
                   AND field_data_field_entity.entity_id = field_revision_field_file_upload.entity_id
                   AND field_data_field_country.entity_id= field_data_field_entity.entity_id
                   AND field_revision_field_file_upload.field_file_upload_fid=file_managed.fid", $args);                            
  $results = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it without the $query->execute(); as according to the docs for [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) the function already executes the query and returns a result.

Try this:

```
$args = array(':entities' => $_REQUEST['entities'], ':countries'=>$_REQUEST['countries']);
$result = db_query("SELECT field_entity_value,field_country_value, filename
                   FROM field_data_field_entity,field_data_field_country , field_revision_field_file_upload, file_managed
                   WHERE ( field_data_field_entity.field_entity_value LIKE :entities
                   AND field_data_field_country.field_country_value= :countries )
                   AND field_data_field_entity.entity_id = field_revision_field_file_upload.entity_id
                   AND field_data_field_country.entity_id= field_data_field_entity.entity_id
                   AND field_revision_field_file_upload.field_file_upload_fid=file_managed.fid", $args);
```

I would say the error is from trying to execute a result.

Comment: The way I used the LIKE keyword. Will it work ?

Comment: I don't see it why it wouldn't, but you would have to try it to find out.